# iOS secure enclave and jailbreak

Tags: ios, keychain, jailbreak

If an iOS device is jailbroken, I understand an attacker cannot extricate key material from the secure enclave. But would they be able to use keys using CryptoKit  within the enclave to encrypt a password stored within keychain?

Or do the CrytpoKit APIs perform some sort of system integrity check before accessing the key material in the enclave to check for system compromise?

Comment: Perhaps? Until it was done, it was believed impossible to jailbreak in the first place. If you want a secure device, you don't jailbreak it.

Comment: It's very difficult to tell what is *possible* just by looking at the design of an architecture. Looking at some [hardware-level attacks](https://cpu.fail/), it may be possible information about the key material may be gathered at some point.